# Individual pledge amount in Stake Pool with multiple pool owners

Tags: stake-pool, pledge

I have some questions about creating a Cardano Staking Pool with multiple owners.

Context:

- Owner 1. Wants to pledge 200,000 ADA.
- Owner 2. Wants to pledge 120,000 ADA.
- Owner 3. Wants to pledge 80,000 ADA.

As the documentation states (https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-node/blob/master/doc/stake-pool-operations/register_stakepool.md), you can provide more than one owner key if there were multiple owners who share the pledge.

So when running the command `cardano-cli stake-pool registration-certificate`, I specify `--pool-pledge 400000000000` for 400K ADA, and including the `--pool-owner-stake-verification-key-file stake.vkey` (Stake Verification Key) for every owner (3 times).

Now, here is where it breaks down. The documentation says that I need to generate a delegation certificate pr. owner, but does not say anyhing about the amount to pledge from each owner.

is there something I'm missing here?

Is the pledge automatically delegated when submitting the certificate?

Does the owner have to manually delegate the amount to pledge from his/here own wallet that we derived the stake.vkey from?

Anyone know how to manage this?

Answer (score 3):

The pool registration certificate only declares who the owners are and what the total pledge is required to be met. The individual pledge owners must register and delegate their stake key just like any other user from their wallet listed as an owner. If the pledge is not met, pool and all delegators get zero rewards. When pledge is met, all owner rewards are assigned to pool rewards stake address. It also very crucial to at least register the pool rewards stake address otherwise all fees and owner rewards will be sent to treasury instead of the pool's rewards address!